# OpenERP: Link to issue from task

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

We currently have both Issues and Tasks being used in our OpenERP installation. You can associate an Issue to a Task which is great! What we want though is to show a link on the Task linking back to the Issue. Is this in any simple way possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a new module that links the task to all the related issues and display a new notebook page of issues in the task form view.

Right now the issue (of project_issue module) is linked to project.task like this:

```
'task_id': fields.many2one('project.task', 'Task', domain="[('project_id','=',project_id)]")
```

Which means that 0..n issues can be linked to one task. In other words, one task is linked to 0..n issues. Thus adding the following field to an inherited `project.task` model should establish the link in the opposite direction:

```
'issue_id': fields.one2many('project.issue', 'task_id', 'Issue', domain="[('project_id','=',project_id)]")
```

In addition, you need a view definition for adding a notebook page or other suitable component on the form, openerp module descriptor and whatnot. What I'm trying to say is that "simple" is a relative concept and this is the simplest way that I can think of.

Comment: but there is already a connection between issues and tasks. why can't i just be able to query issues with a task id so i can get the associated issues for a given task id?

Answer (score 0):

There is a community module for this, `project_issue_task`, at the [official app store](https://www.openerp.com/apps/7.0/project_issue_task/). It's part of the [Project for Service Management](https://launchpad.net/project-service) community project.

It also adds to Tasks a "Related Issue", under the "Extra Info" tab:

[image]

Comment: Daniel this is what we are using. what i need is a link on the task to link you back to the issue it's related to! Can't find a way for this module to do it of the box. or is there?

Comment: It does so, it's just a little out of sight. Improved the answer to explain it.